# How does this normalized example work?

Tags: database, database-design, database-development, normalization

I had the following DB schema:

```
Customer   Car     Rental
-------   ----     ------
Name      Name     Car_ID
ID        ID       Customer_ID
                   Date
```

This is said to be non normalized as the date can repeat (multiple customers can rent a car at the same day). So the teacher said it should be like:

```
Customer  Car Date
------    --- ----
```

and linked with foreign keys.

Well I do not get that - how can I then simply enter that "John rented a BMW on 2/3/2013"?

Comment: You would still have the Rental table only instead of holding a date it would have a link to that date in the date table. Date: (id:111, date:2/3/2013) Rental: (car_id: 123, customer_id: 456, date_id: 111)

Comment: The point is - they said so - there is no need for rental table now.

Comment: You _do_ need a Rentals table to link customers and cars together on any given date, otherwise a car can be rented only once (`Car.CustomerID`) or a customer can once rent one car (`Customer.CarID`), which is just silly.

Comment: ...or you can only have one transaction per day. Also silly.

Comment: @Kilian how would you save multiple transactions for the same customer or car, without duplication and without a Rentals table?

Comment: Could the Date table hold Car FK, Customer FK and Date?

Comment: Yes it could, but then it would just be a badly-named Rentals table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would enter that fact by first creating (or looking up) a record in `Date` to represent Mar 2, 2013, then create a new record in `Rental` with *three* foreign keys. (You still need the table `Rental`, otherwise you can't represent arbitrary re-rentings of a customer or a car - or on the same date.)

However, that is surely unnecessary. A date is one scalar piece of information - the fact that it's formatted XX/YY/ZZZZ or MMM DD, YYYY doesn't affect its identity, and formatting rules shouldn't be imposed by the storing the display form in databases anyway. My opinion is that storing dates as a scalar field in another table (here: `Rental`) is perfectly normal - a date is effectively a day number, i.e. no worse than any other foreign key you'd use.

Comment: In this example, I agree about the date, but there could be other information associated with a date like, billing period, IsHoliday. and might even need to be linked to a fee schedule or discount table.